# Is there any way to sync addressbook by CardDAV on Java

Tags: java, addressbook

It seems that CardDAV and LDAP become a popular way to share contacts with servers.I am looking for a library to sync my server contact with others(Google,yahoo,iCloud etc).I only found CalDAV and WebDAV libraries,such as ical4j.It seemed to used in calendar,but still cannot find a way to access to addressbook.

Is any one can help?

Comment: looking for the same thing, and I finally diceded to make something based on sardine (work in progress)